# Is there any tool to Convert magento 1 Product import csv file to magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, csv, importexport

I have `Magento 1 Product Import CSV file`, I need to `convert Magento 2 Product Import CSV Format`.

Is there any tool out there?.         If not there means,

Suggest me How to Convert it.  Because

1. Magento 1 Product Import file have More Columns form magento 2 product import csv file.
2. I need clarification about fields, which magento 1 Product import file field is equal to Magento 2. and what are the fields are need in magento 2 from magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to use Official Magento Data Migration tool which will allow you migrate products, customer and more!

- Manual http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html
- GitHub https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting Magento 1 to Magento 2 then you can migrate the Magento. You can simply use data-migration-tool for that which is by default provided by Magento.

If you have csv and you want to import the products then you need to make sure that all the attributes and their options are created.

Also you need to make changes in csv get from Magento 1. And make it work for Magento 2. Then you can import all the products in Magento 2.